# Why is $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)g(x+1)$ undefined, where $f(x)=2$ if $x=1$, $f(x)=\cos(\pi x/2)$ if $x\neq1$, $g(x)=1$ if $x<2$, and $g(x)=-1$ if $x\geq2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2&\text{if }x=1\\\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}1&\text{if }x<2\\-1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Why is $$\lim_\limits{x\to1}f(x)g(x+1)$$ undefined?

Answer (score 1):

The limit **does** exist. Notice that, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$,

$$\lvert f(x)g(x+1)\rvert\leq\lvert f(x)\rvert=\left\lvert \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right\rvert.$$

As $\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\to0$ as $x\to 1$, it follows by the Squeeze theorem that

$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)g(x+1)=0.$$